# How to backup ruby gems?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

How do you backup ruby gems? I am re-installing the Operating System so I would like to know how to back up ruby gems so that I can re-install it when I have installed the Operating System?

Is it also possible to install gems on a computer without internet access?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To get a list of the names of your gems, do `gem list --no-versions`. Make a directory (such as `gem-exports`) Save that list to a file inside that directory, then remove the headers and empty lines. (The automation options are for *nix systems.)

Take that list and

```
xargs gem unpack < $LISTNAME
```

inside the directory. This should take the gem names and run a `gem unpack $GEMNAME` on all of them. You will now have all of the gems' sources in their respective directories. Copy the directory to the new OS.

You can then, in the directory, run

```
xargs -I gemname gem build gemname/gemname.gemspec < $LISTNAME
```

This should build all the gems you just exported, without needing an internet connection. IF you have a connection, then you can just

```
xargs gem install < $LISTNAME
```

That will install the latest versions of all of them.

Comment: When I run `gem list --no-versions`, I get an error message as shown in the link here. http://i.imgur.com/SZnlb.png. How do you backup if you are running windows?

Comment: Try a normal `gem list`, then edit out the versions. You'll have to do everything manually (open the gem name file in notepad and use the up arrow and replace the names to make it easier). Also, if you are going to Windows again, *please* install [Cygwin](http://cygwin.com). You can get Ruby, Gems, and Rails by following [this](http://phaseshiftllc.com/articles/2008/10/02/setting-up-rails-on-windows-with-cygwin.html). Cygwin is a POSTIX-compliant interface to Windows, meaning its commands and shell are **loads** better than cmd.exe.

Comment: I'd do a `gem list --no-versions | sed '/^*/ d'` for a clean output of installed gems.